# Return certain elements of a phrase after special characters

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm a newbie to regular expressions and would need to parse the following phrases in BigQuery.

```
phrase
custom3==10-25% sale&+brand==xxx
custom2==30-50% sale&+brand==yyy
```

to return

```
output
10-25% sale and xxx
30-50% sale and yyy
```

Below is the furthest point that I've been able to reach so far"

```
REGEXP_CONTAINS(phrase, r"\==") then REGEXP_EXTRACT(phrase, r"\==(.*)")
```

which obviously does not do the job given its output

```
10-25% sale&+brand==xxx
30-50% sale&+brand==yyy
```

Any thought on this is appreciated.

Comment: You could use a capturing group to match your values `==([^&\r\n]+)` https://regex101.com/r/I4aX4z/1 or perhaps use replace `\S+==(.*?)&+\S+==` https://regex101.com/r/QbY74S/1

Comment: i still didn't get this question, even despite the given answer :o(

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant what's up with this question? :)

Comment: just didn't get what exactly your use case. even looking into the answer - still not clear ...

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant This can be used to clean the GA data stored in BigQuery tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `REGEX_REPLACE` and capturing groups:

```
WITH data AS (
  SELECT * FROM UNNEST(
    ['custom3==10-25% sale&+brand==xxx','custom2==30-50% sale&+brand==yyy']
  ) phrase
)

SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(phrase
  , r'.*==([^ ]* sale).*(...)'
  , r'\1 and \2') 
FROM data



10-25% sale and xxx 
30-50% sale and yyy
```